# How to count number of fields those have same values in firstore using Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I want to count the number of fields named `'In'` with the value `true` in my `firestore` database.

[image: Sample Database]

**This is How the Database has been linked in .py**

```
def build(self):
    import firebase_admin
    from firebase_admin import credentials
    from firebase_admin import firestore

    cred = credentials.Certificate("cred.json")
    firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

    self.db = firestore.client()

    self.screen_manager.add_widget(Builder.load_file('kv/main.kv'))
    return self.screen_manager
```

But I have no idea to count it. Please help me to find a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the Python examples in the Firebase documentation on [querying Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#python), that should be something like:

```
cities_ref = db.collection(u'Users')

query_ref = cities_ref.where(u'In', u'==', true)

docs = query_ref.get()

print(len(docs))

for doc in docs:
    print(f'{doc.id} => {doc.to_dict()}')
```